# Ionic Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed ionic through there documentation but when I try to run any ionic command it says invalid or unexpected token, how to solve it, below are some screenshots

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg2Z9.png)

Comment: Where do you run this command? inside the/a project?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downgrading my node js version to 12.0.0 , one of the developers said always use stable versions instead of unstable versions